# Dart equatable with non final variables

Tags: dart, equatable

I have class with final variable (hash) and some other non-final variables.
Hash is unique value. And objects are stored in Set. Set uses '==' operand to check equality of objects. I want to override "=="  and "hashCode" in my class and work with Set array.
To avoid using boilerplate  code I want to use Equatable extension. Like this

```
class User extends Equatable {
    final String hash;
    String balance;
    bool state;
    ....

    @override
    List<Object> get props => [hash];
} .... Set<User> users
```

Is it correct way to use Equatable in my case, 'cause it is uses with immutable classes.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Overriding `hashCode` to depend on non-`final` fields is usually not recommended because it can make `Set`s and `Map`s and other data structures that depend on `hashCode` internally inconsistent.  Suppose you have such an object and insert it into a `Set`.  Later, you mutate that object by assigning a new value to that field, but the `Set` would still have a reference to that object with the old hash code.  For example, consider:

```dart
class Foo {
  String s;

  Foo(this.s);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    return other is Foo && s == other.s;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => s.hashCode;

  @override
  String toString() => s;
}

void main() {
  var foo = Foo('foo');
  var someSet = <Foo>{foo};
  foo.s = 'bar';
  print(someSet.contains(foo)); // Prints: false
  someSet.add(foo);
  print(someSet.length); // Prints: 2
  print(someSet); // Prints: {bar, bar}
}
```

and now `someSet` would have two references to the exact same object, which violates its goal of storing unique objects.

A `Map` would have similar problems.

Since `hashCode` is tied to `operator ==`, this consequently also means that you usually shouldn't override `operator ==` to depend on non-`final` fields.

You can get away with it if you can guarantee that you never mutate your objects while they're being referenced by a `Set`/`Map`/etc. or if you can guarantee that whenever you want to add your object to a `Set`/`Map`/etc. that you create a copy of your object and add that copy instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your use is correct.

You use `Equatable` only with the final field, so the equality and hash code should be stable over time, and the `hash` field is unique, so it can serve as identifier for the object.
If your `hash` field ends up not unique, you'll have two distinguishable objects that are equal, so ... don't do that.

Not sure how much you gain from using `Equatable`, though. If you wrote the equality and hash code yourself, it would just be:

```dart
  bool operator==(Object other) => other is Foo && hash == other.hash;
  int get hashCode => hash.hashCode;
```

Comment: Yes, hash is unique and immutable. I want to avoid boilerplate code using  Equatable  but, you are right, gain will seem questionable. Thanks